# How to access the IApplicationBuilder and IWebHost instances in and outside an ASP.Net Core controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I would like to understand if it is possible to reference the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder (app) and the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost (host) instances from within an ASP.Net Core 2.x controller method. And also, if the same can be done from a referenced class library method.

I tried injecting the interfaces in the controller constructor like so:

```
public ResourcesController(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public ResourcesController(IWebHost host)
{
    ...
}
```

But it resulted in the following `InvalidOperationException`s being thrown:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder' while attempting to activate 'blablabla.ResourcesController'

and

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost' while attempting to activate 'blablabla.ResourcesController'.

What am I missing? Do I need to call some extension methods in the `ConfigureServices` method?

I also probably could have tried packaging the instances in a service class and injecting the same into the controller but I thought there'd be a better way than that.

I am also wondering if the same thing can be achieved inside an instance method of a class sitting in a separate class library referenced by the main ASP.Net Core application.

As for why I need this; honestly there's no particular reason. I just experimenting with ASP.Net Core to better my understanding and ran into these questions.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why you want to do what you want to do but Did you register `IApplicationBuilder` or `IWebHost` to the DI container?

Comment: Maybe explaining why you need this is better?

Comment: @emrah, no i did not. i expected they would be automatically registered to the DI container by the ASP.Net Core framework just like `IConfiguration`, `IHostingEnvironment`, etc. i don't have to explicitly register these interfaces to the DI container.

Comment: @jpgrassi, like i already mentioned in my post i have no specific needs but just trying to understand if this is possible or not, technically. if it is not possible, so be it.